# what version of java Sevlets does my server run

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

looking here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String)

it says that getPart from HttpServletRequest  is supported "Since: Servlet 3.0".

how do I know if this is the case for me or not ?
is it the version of tomcat that I am running ? and if so what version should I have for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 is supported by tomcat 7, see [tomcat versions](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatVersions)

Comment: Thanks, could you add another bit of info:
and what about when I am at the development environment ? (eclipse) what does it use? JDK? and if so, what version of the JDK do I need for this ?

Comment: The question doesn't ask anything about Eclipse etc. FYI you can have any number of Tomcats configured in Eclipse, I'm using parallel installations of Tomcat 6+7 in my development environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, could you add another bit of info: and what about when I am at the development environment ? (eclipse) what does it use? JDK? and if so, what version of the JDK do I need for this ?

Eclipse uses which ever Server profile and Java platform that you tell it to use via your preferences:

- The server profile is selected via "Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment"; e.g. you can select versions of Tomcat, Websphere, Glassfish and so on.
- The java platform is selected via "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs" and (optionally) "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environment".

Answer (score 0):

Use [ServletContext.getEffectiveMajorVersion](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getEffectiveMajorVersion%28%29) to get the version of servlet spec.